# Printing an entire character array after looping through every point in a rectangular area

Tags: c, arrays, unix, complex-numbers, mandelbrot

I'm using a double for-loop in order to check every point (coordinate pair) in a rectangular area from (-2.0, -1.12) to (0.47, 1.12) to see whether it belongs to the Mandelbrot set. If it does, I want to print a 1. Likewise, if it does not, I want to print a 0. The basic idea is to print, line by line, an array of characters that displays a simplified Mandelbrot set.

This is my main function:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "complex.h"
#include "mandelbrot.h"

#define STEP_X   0.06175
#define STEP_Y   0.07466                

int main(void){

    int i = 0;
    char arr[50];
    complex_t c, abs, max;
    max.real = 10000;
    max.imag = 0;

    for (c.imag = -1.12; c.imag <= 1.12; c.imag += STEP_Y){
            for (c.real = -2.0; c.real <= 0.47; c.real += STEP_X){
                    abs = abs_complex(mandelbrot(c,15));
                    if (abs.real < max.real){ 
                            arr[i] = 1;
                            i++;
                    } 
                    else{
                            arr[i] = 0;
                            i++;
                    }
            }
            printf("%s", arr);
            i = 0;  
    }
}
```

The program compiles just fine, but does not produce an output. I know I must not be printing the array the right way, but for the life of me I can not figure out how to do it.

Any feedback, hints, or tips would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Where are you *nul-terminating* `arr` and what's the difference between `1` and ASCII `'1'`? (hint: [ASCII Table and Description](http://www.asciitable.com/))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problems you are having are two-fold. (1) you are copying *decimal values* to `arr` (e.g. `0` and `1`) instead of ASCII characters (`'0'` and `'1'`). Decimal `0` and `1` are non-printable. Ironically decimal `0` is the *nul-terminating* character, so if `if (abs.real >= max.real)` for `i == 0` `arr` holds the *empty-string*.

Second you call `printf` without having insured the final character is the *nul-terminating* character. (you can do this by default by initializing `char arr[MAXC] = "";` and insuring your loop is limited to `i + 1 < 50 && c.real <= 0.47` or you can simply affirmatively terminate `arr` with `arr[i] = 0;` before calling `i = 0;` (or move your declaration of `i` inside the first `for` loop and initialize).

This is untested (I don't have your local headers), but it looks like you intended:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "complex.h"
#include "mandelbrot.h"

#define MAXC     50
#define STEP_X   0.06175
#define STEP_Y   0.07466                

int main(void){

    complex_t c, abs, max;
    max.real = 10000;
    max.imag = 0;

    for (c.imag = -1.12; c.imag <= 1.12; c.imag += STEP_Y) {

        int i = 0;             /* declare/initialize i & arr here */
        char arr[MAXC] = "";   /* set to all zero */

        for (c.real = -2.0; 
            i + 1 < MAXC && c.real <= 0.47;  /* limit to 49 chars max */
            c.real += STEP_X) {

            abs = abs_complex (mandelbrot (c,15));

            if (abs.real < max.real) 
                arr[i++] = '1';   /* assign character '1' */
            else
                arr[i++] = '0';   /* assign character '0' */
        }
        arr[i] = 0;               /* nul-terminate line */
        printf ("%s\n", arr);     /* output line */
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Give it a try and let me know if you have further questions.

Comment: A single zero is officially an octal constant, but it is indistinguishable from a decimal zero.

Comment: You got me there... My octal constant RADAR must be faulty `:)`, Good catch JL. I know exactly what you are saying, but must admit it never entered my thought process during the answer...

Comment: That was spot on. You sir, are a god amongst men. As a beginner programmer, I'm still in disbelief as to how you did that, header files missing and all, without even the smallest syntax error.

Comment: Every once in a while -- even a blind squirrel finds a nut.... As long as your headers were good, the code was fairly straight forward. Don't worry, you will get there soon.